# JavaScript window.open(filename) doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This works on Firefox but not on IE

```
window.open('/documents/some%20file.doc');
```

On IE it would open a new tab and immediately closes it. No save dialog.

Is there any way to let user download a file on IE using JavaScript if we have the file URL?
(The file URL is dynamic so it cannot be an `<a href=''>` tag)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.location.href = '/documents/some%20file.doc';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open("/documents/some%20file.doc","_self","fullscreen=no,toolbar=yes,width=800,height=600,menubar=yes,status=no,scroll=yes");
```